# Postfix-Bypass header_checks for some senders

Tags: postfix

I want to bypass header_checks/body_checks for some incoming sender addresses (or something like a whitelist).

I tried so far to use the FILTER option in header_checks with another port in master.cf regarding the option receive_override_options with "no_header_body_checks", but then my log says:

`"warning: connect to transport 127.0.0.1: No such file or directory"`

my header_checks:

```
/^From:.*domain\.tld/                                FILTER 127.0.0.1:10026
```

my master.cf:

```
172.0.0.1:10026 inet  n       -       -       -      -      smtpd
 -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks
```

I also tried in master.cf and header_checks:
"localhost:10026" and just "10026" instead of "127.0.0.1:10026"

Thanks for your help,
Martin

EDIT1: spelling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quite close.  You should specify the protocol (`smtp`) too, like `FILTER smtp:127.0.0.1:10026`.

So

```
/^From: whatever-match/ FILTER smtp:127.0.0.1:10026
```

```
10026 inet  n -       n       -       4      smtpd
        -o receive_override_options=no_unknown_recipient_checks
        [whatever smtpd options you want]
```